# I want to remove unwanted symbols from a column in my dataframe. How do I go about doing this? (I'm using Python)

Tags: pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FYgSp.png [1]

I've included a link to an image of the head of my dataframe. As you can see, the prices column has periods, commas, dollar signs, as well as prices in different currency.

I would like to iterate through all the elements in the prices column and remove everything except for numbers. Moreover, the only number I want is the number that shows the price of an object in Canadian currency.

Here is the code I've tried

```
df['prices']=df['prices'].map(lambda x: x.strip('.,'))
```

This didn't work. I've also tried the following

```
df['prices']=df['prices'].map(lambda x: x.lstrip('.,').rstrip('CA'))
```

which also didn't work.

What would you suggest I do? If you could also explain why you use the code that you use, then that would help me immensely in learning the Python language. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
df['prices']=df['prices'].apply(lambda x: re.sub('[^0-9]+', ‘’, x))
```

**Edit:** I missed the part where you said you want just the canadian currency. So assuming the the middle part (CA1234) is the format for canadian currency,

```
df['prices']=df['prices'].apply(lambda x: float(x.split(“,”)[1][2:]))
```

Comment: I got the following error: could not convert string to float: 'A$219.99'

Comment: I cannot see these symbols in the picture provided by you, so assuming A$ is everwhere, you can replace 2 by 4 in the above line of code